Are predicted probabilities from logistic regression in a case-control design valid?
I have been reading about and learning how to obtain predicted probabilities from a logistic regression and if wanted, to convert these to a risk ratio. But it occurs to me that a binary outcome is clearly not the same across different study designs. Am I correct in thinking that it only makes sense to compute probabilities from a logistic model if the study is a cohort (forward) design rather than case-control, as in the latter, the 'risk' isn't representative of the population as you have selected on the outcome? So in a case-control design, one should stop at odds-ratios and go no further, in terms of reporting and describing results?

Strictly speaking, it depends on how you did the regression.
If you did the overwhelmingly most common analysis, just logistic regression on the data as observed, then the predicted probabilities will be much too high because the intercept will be too high.
You might in principle have done logistic regression with an offset for the log odds ratio of sampling in cases vs controls, which would correct the intercept and give correct predictions. Or, you might have done weighted logistic regression using sampling weights, which would also give correct predictions.
If you know the odds of sampling for controls (I'm assuming 100% sampling for cases) then you can correct the bias in the intercept for the usual and get valid predictions, which might well be worth doing.

Thank you. Ok, so two potential fixes - correct the intercept or use sampling weights in a standard glm call. Any tips on where I can find information about doing either of these two things (ideally in R)?
